# What are digital libraries with a significant amount of public-domain genealogical content?

Tags: records, sources

I'm trying to compile a list of digital libraries that are of particular interest to genealogists. I'm aware of archive.org, the Digital Public Library of America, and Chronicling America. What are other digital libraries with a significant amount of public-domain genealogical content?

Comment: Strictly public domain or also content under free licensing?

Comment: good point - either would be fine.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  Here you appear to be seeking to compile a list by using a question that amounts to "can you suggest what should be on that list".  This is too broad for the focused Q&A of the Main site but would be fine to ask in the [Roots Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6003/roots).

Comment: Please add the great ADTPlus library. http://adtplus.arcanum.hu It contains dozens of volumes about Hungarian genealogy, but unfortunately the access is granted after one pays the subscruption

Comment: Thank you George. Unfortunately I'm only looking for public-access libraries right now.